# How to send a GET request exactly like I have it in fiddler?

Tags: c#, request, httpwebrequest, webrequest, http-get

So I am trying to build a program in C#. I want to send a really specific request. Exactly as I receive it in fiddler. Right now I am using fiddlers composer feature to send the request. [Here is how I get the request in fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfVEY.png)

How can I send it exactly as shown on the picture but in a C# console application?

Basically looking for a way to get a request in fiddler and implement it directly in to my code in the format that fiddler gives it to me.(In fiddler I can save the request in .txt format. If I could use that same .txt format to send the request then it would be really helpful)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create HttpClient instance and set the headers shown in the fiddler to the same values.  Hope this helps.  Your URL was HTTPS hence you will need to set for certificate validation OR you will have to set avoid certificate errors on the call.

```
// Create a client
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

// Add a new Request Message
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://yoursitehere/");

// Add our custom headers
requestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "User-Agent-Here");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Connection", "MIME-Type-Here");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "value-from-fiddler");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "value-from-fiddler");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "value-from-fiddler");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "value-from-fiddler");
requestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "value-from-fiddler");

// Send the request to the server
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

// Just as an example I'm turning the response into a string here
string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: User-Agent, Connection and Accept are restricted. How do I go about to change them?